# Include the -u CURL parameter in HTTP Request in apex

Tags: callout, httprequest, curl

I want to make a request from salesforce to a CURL definition like this:

```
    curl https://sandbox-api.openpay.mx/v1/mzdtln0bmtms6o3kck8f/customers/ag4nktpdzebjiye1tlze/charges \
   -u sk_e568c42a6c384b7ab02cd47d2e407cab: \
   -H "Content-type: application/json" \
   -X POST -d '{
   "method" : "store",
   "amount" : 100,
   "description" : "Cargo con tienda",
   "order_id" : "oid-00053",
   "due_date" : "2014-05-20T13:45:00"
} '
```

the only parameter I don't know how to include is the -u

Any idea around this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally could send my request following the next steps:

1. Using Basic Authentication in my Authorization header
2. Convert the username value to Base64+' '(blank space as I don't have password)
3. Put in the Authorization Header Basic value generated before.

It worked for me.